# Android reading large Files (out of memory exception)

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to read large files (>14MB) into my Android App.
Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
InputStream stream = manager.open(Filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
Scontent = br.readLine();  //I just load one big line that is bigger than 14 MB
```

But I'm getting an out of memory exception on a ~14MB allocation.
I read something about a maximum app size of 16MB (depending on the device), but I can't find a good way to load that much data.

What would be the easiest solution to load such big files?

Comment: Do you need to read the whole file into memory ??? can you process it in smaller chunks ???

Answer (score 1):

instead of using a big files use multiple smaller files (~1MB). Then read those sequentially if you need to read all data at a time

Answer (score 0):

The `InputStreamReader` class will let you read the file byte by byte.  You're already using that class, however you're embedding it into a `BufferedReader` class.  So discard the `BufferedReader` and read your big file byte by byte youself.  If you do that, and process the bytes as you go, then you won't need to read the whole file in a single operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can read char by char but again, but watch about allocation remove reference after usage of this smaller block, so Garbage Cleaner can return that memory.